# Random Number Guessing Game for Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to make a program that will generate a random number, and you have to guess it by typing in the answer. The problem is that it won't match the right number [as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OEwt.jpg/%22as%20shown).

Objects:
2 Labels, 1 textbox, 1 Command button

My first code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim Num, Random As Integer

Label2.Caption = ""
Num = Val(Text1.Text)
Randomize (Random)
Random = Val(Label1.Caption)
Label1.Caption = Int(10 * Rnd + 1)

For Num = 1 To Num
    If Num = Random Then
    Label2.Caption = "you won "
    Else
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need that for loop, its checking each number up to the number you guessed.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim Num, Random As Integer

    Label2.Caption = ""
    Num = Val(Text1.Text)
    Randomize (Random)
    Random = Val(Label1.Caption)
    Label1.Caption = Int(10 * Rnd + 1)


        If Num = Random Then
        Label2.Caption = "you won "
        Else
        End If

    End Sub
```

to debug it put

```
        If Num = Random Then
        Label2.Caption = "you won "
        Else
        Label2.Caption = "The number " & Num & " Does not equal " & Random
        End If
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it's also a nice addition to my form. I also changed the bottom code to fix the result if you don't mind. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the current code will always result in number zero being the first "randomly" generated number. Second, the formula will produce a predictable random number sequence.

The issue behind this is that computers are not smart and cannot really create random numbers, that's why you need to "seed" them with Randomize to sort of "shake" the dice and come up with a different number. But, if you randomize with the same number, it will produce exactly the same sequence of "random" numbers.

For example, if you use your code, it will always produce the following sequence of numbers: 0, 8, 7, 5 ...

That's why you need to "seed" the random number with... a random number! LOL. But how do you get a random number? Technically, you can't, but you can cheat. You can do `Randomize (Timer)` or `Randomize`, which takes Timer as a parameter and what it does is "seeds" the random number generation with a number of seconds and milliseconds elapsed since midnight. So, the only time where you will get the same sequence of random numbers if you click the button to guess the random number every day at exactly the same second and millisecond.

You can try and expand on this theory by adding day, month or year  - that would expand the "seed" exponentially and you will never see repeating sequence of random numbers, but it is extremely hard to do that because once you start playing around with large seed numbers you will encounter weird issues such as if you change a very large number by 1, it would still generate the same sequence of random numbers (in my test scenario, randomizing with any number in the range from 5969992 to 5969995 will result in the same sequence of random numbers: 9, 8, 6, 6, 1). This is probably a limitation of the Randomize function itself. Personally, I don't think its worth trying to go beyond seeding with timer.

Below is your code adjusted to generate a more "random" sequence of numbers:

```
Dim Num, Random As Integer

Label2.Caption = ""
Num = Val(Text1.Text)
Randomize
Label1.Caption = Int(10 * Rnd + 1)
Random = Val(Label1.Caption)

If Num = Random Then
    Label2.Caption = "you won "
Else
    Label2.Caption = "The number " & Num & " Does not equal " & Random
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dim num, Random as integer

label2.caption =""
num = val(text1.text)

randomize
label1.caption = int((10 +1-1)*rnd+1)
random = val(label1.caption)

if num = random then
label2.caption ="you won"
else
label2.caption = "Try again"
end if
```